# State changes after second click of onPress in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a made a custom checkbox for my application.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkValue1: false,
      color1: 'white',
    };
  }

checkBox1 = () => {
        if (this.state.checkValue1 == false) {
          this.setState({
            color1: 'white',
            checkValue1: true,
          });
        } else if (this.state.checkValue1 == true) {
          this.setState({
            color1: '#70AD47',
            checkValue1: false,
          });
        }
      };

  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.checkBorder} onPress={this.checkBox1}>
    <Icon name="checkmark" type="ionicon" size={20} color={this.state.color1} />
  </TouchableOpacity>


checkBorder: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderColor: '#7F7F7F',
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
```

It's working all fine. But only problem is that, icon color changes after second click. After that it changes with every click. Issue is only that it should change color after first click itself. I don't know what I am missing out in my code

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
checkBox1 = () => {
  if (this.state.checkValue1 == false) {
    this.setState({
      color1: "#70AD47", // change here
      checkValue1: true,
    });
  } else if (this.state.checkValue1 == true) {
    this.setState({
      color1: "white",  // change here
      checkValue1: false,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks you. That was such a silly mistake on my part